# PHP session cookie sessionid

Tags: php, session, cookies, sessionid

in PHP i used session and cookie not urlrewriting with PHPSESSID.
but when i opened cookie then i saw the key value pair.but one of them is 
path : /

what does path mean,can you explain elaborately.
if i change the path value to /abc/cdddddddddd/efc then what does that mean?

Comment: paste actual cookie value that you have seen

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's part of a standard cookie

> **Domain and path**
>
> Each cookie also has a domain and a
>   path. The domain tells the browser to
>   which domain the cookie should be
>   sent. If you don't specify it, it
>   becomes the domain of the page that
>   sets the cookie, in the case of this
>   page `www.quirksmode.org`. Please note
>   that the purpose of the domain is to
>   allow cookies to cross sub-domains. My
>   cookie will not be read by
>   `search.quirksmode.org` because its
>   domain is `www.quirksmode.org` . When I
>   set the domain to `quirksmode.org`, the
>   search sub-domain may also read the
>   cookie. I cannot set the cookie domain
>   to a domain I'm not in, I cannot make
>   the domain `www.microsoft.com` . Only
>   `quirksmode.org` is allowed, in this
>   case.
>
> The path gives you the chance to
>   specify a directory where the cookie
>   is active. So if you want the cookie
>   to be only sent to pages in the
>   directory `cgi-bin`, set the path to
>   `/cgi-bin`. Usually the path is set to
>   `/`, which means the cookie is valid
>   throughout the entire domain. This
>   script does so, so the cookies you can
>   set on this page will be sent to any
>   page in the `www.quirksmode.org` domain
>   (though only this page has a script
>   that searches for the cookies and does
>   something with them).
>
> [Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

You may want to [read more about cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).